# Can't run custom module on AWS/nodejs. Exits with error: Cannot find module

Tags: node.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, parse-server

I want to switch to a fork of the parse-server module on AWS elastic beanstalk, but no matter what I try I get this error when the server tries to start up:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'parse-server'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/index.js:64:21)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
```

The original module works without a problem:

- in package.json:

  ```
  "parse-server": "3.10.0",
  ```
- but neither of these ones do work:

  ```
  "parse-server": "https://github.com/andrewking0207/parse-server.git#appleAuth",
  ```

  ```
  "parse-server": "andrewking0207/parse-server.git#appleAuth",
  ```

when I ssh into to the ec2 instance the module is installed inside node-modules.
What am I missing here?? Locally on my machine everything runs fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not install directly from a GitHub fork because it does not have the `lib` folder which is created during the build process. There is a workaround though:

1 - Clone your fork to your machine
2 - Remove the lib folder from the .gitignore file
3 - Run `npm install`
4 - Run `npm build`
5 - Commit the changes to your local git
6 - Push the commit to your remote fort branch at GitHub

Then you can try to install it again and it should work. I just wanted to make clear that it is a workaround and not the recommended way to use Parse Server. If you explain what you want to achieve by using your own fork, I can try to advice about the "right" way to be done.

Comment: Thank you!! This did the trick. I am wondering though, why does the fork then run locally? Is AWS doing something different than running "npm install"?
As for the functionality, this fork fixes a bug with Apple Sign In. It's already a pull request (https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/pull/6416), but I can't wait for it to become part of the master branch (can't submit to the app store without that fix).

Comment: AWS is running npm install but your GitHub repo didn't have the lib folder (because it was in the gitignore file). In the official repo, the lib folder is sent to npm and AWS installs from npm (and not from GitHub).